# IE 11 Jquery 1.7.1 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jquery-1.7

We are using `Jquery 1.7.1 with IE 8` for a long time and we planned to migrate to `IE11`.
But when we run our application, we are getting the **error below**:

```
File: jquery-1.7.1.js
Line No:1437
Code: delete div.test;
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue.I tried with IE Enterprise mode but that also doesn't solve the problem.

Someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Upgrade to jQuery 2, jQuery 1 supports older browsers.

Comment: Can you update the jquery version to one with IE11 support. The changes between IE10 and 11 are to big.

Comment: @ SHammelburg @ reporter thanks for your response.I am new to jquery. We have designed a internal jquery component using jquery1.7.1. If we upgrade will that impact my existing componet and code ie) does jquery 1.7 code will be impacted if i upgrade jquery to 2.x.

Comment: @SHammelburg jQuery 1.x supports IE 6+, which AFAIK, includes IE11

Comment: I don't think this is an IE11 problem. I think somewhere in your code you're calling a jquery method with the wrong arguments and that's why jquery bugs internally. I remember I had a bug like that because I was using .find('.' + SomeClassName) and at some point SomeClassName was null so jquery bugged internally.

Comment: @frenchie thanks for your response. I have debugged the code while loading the jquery1.7.1 we are getting that error . ie) <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.17/js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Well, if you can isolate the problem we might be able to help you but we can't guess the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @frenchie thansk for your reply.I changed the jquery version from 1.7.1 to Jquery2.x we dont get that error but the component we are using is not working as expected. But while debugging(using 1.7.1) we have removed all the java script js imports put only jquery-1.7.1.js and put a alert on ready method as a first step we dont get alert we are getting teh error first followed by alert.